# Error installing package pip install orange3==3.30

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, orange

I would like to install pip install orange3==3.30 in jupyter notebook (On Windows 11 and python 3.12). I get this error when I run !pip install orange3==3.30 code.

````
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\shox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\shox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\shox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vs35mwsq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\shox\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vs35mwsq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 520, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 472, in setup_package
        File "<string>", line 166, in write_version_py
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.```

**I would be very grateful if anyone can advise me on a way to solve this issue.**
````

Comment: Did you try pip installing the missing module (`imp`)?

Comment: `imp` is not supported by (removed from) python 3.12 (https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/imp.html). You need to either drop back to python 3.11, move forward to a newer version of `Orange3` that (hopefully) supports python 3.12, or patch `Orange3` to use `importlib` yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. My jupyter notebook demonstrates the same error in all versions of Orange.

Comment: A quick search of the repo suggests to me that the only instance of `import imp` is in [setup.py](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/setup.py#L166) You might clone the repo and patch that yourself and see if that gets you going again. You could potentially just hardcode the version in a pinch.

Comment: Concerning `!pip install orange3==3.30`: While it most likely won't help or make any difference in this case because you seem to be having additional issues with other dependencies for that package, in line with seeing "is likely not a problem with pip", you will have a better experience going forward in modern Jupyter if you switch to using the magic variation of the install command, specifically here that would be `%pip install orange3==3.30`. Use of an exclamation point with install commands doesn't insure it installs to the correct environment. ...

Comment: <continued> The magic variation of this command was added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is backing the active .ipynb in which you run the installation, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). More at top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about why the exclamation point for installations is deficient and can lead to issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advices. But in both options my jupyter notebook demonstrates the same error. I do not know what to do

Comment: You are trying to use the cutting edge version of Python as JonSG pointed out in the second comment here. His advice was excellent. When Python gets updated things get dropped and it takes a while for other packages to propagate changes needing to be effective. What you are seeing is a symptom of this. **Another option**, beyond JonSG's excellent advice, would be to install [the Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download) of Python/Jupyter ecosystem. It should set itself up on your computer with working Jupyter and I believe Orange is already included in the base install. ...

Comment: <continued> If you do choose that route, you should though work through the getting started that Anaconda has as going forward your primary package manager will be Anaconda/conda and you'll only resort to `pip` when there is no other option.  Beyond that, others are reluctant to recommend it to no users because it adds more complexity that in the long run is a feature: Anaconda/conda adds another layer of package management using environments. So you can have Python 3.9 over there with Pandas 1.15 and in another project be using Python 3.11 with Pandas 2.24.